# Combine two different programms PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

i want to combine two different programs in the same code but i can't find out how.The program must echo the numbers 1 to 100 but for the multiples of 7 instead of the numbers i want to echo the word "multiseven" and instead of the numbers 5 i want to echo the word "multifive" for the multiples of 5.
the code for this is:

```
<?php 

for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)    

    if($i%7==0)
    {
    echo ("multiseven")."\n";
    }
    else if($i%5==0)
    {
        echo ("multifive")."\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $i ."\n";
    }

?>
```

The second program must echo the word "common" for the common multiples of 7 and 5.The code of this is:

```
<?php 

for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)    

    if($i%7==0 && $i%5==0)
    {
    echo ("Common")."\n";
    }
    else {
        echo $i."\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: And where is the problem ?

Comment: How to combine them in one php file program

Comment: How about opening a file and putting one after the other? That combines them into the same file. Or what about having two echo's in your if statement? That combines them. Or what about having them in two files and then having a third include both files? That combines them into one program. Do you see the problem yet? You're not being clear on what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i=1; $i<=100; $i++)    

    if($i%7==0 and $i%5==0)
    {
        echo ("common")."\n";
    }
    else if($i%7==0)
    {
        echo ("multiseven")."\n";
    }
    else if($i%5==0)
    {
        echo ("multifive")."\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $i ."\n";
    }
```

You just put the more restrictive comparisson first...